# Is there a way to create a generic function from either of these two functions? (Generic Array to String)

Tags: c#, linq, generic-programming

I have the following two functions, is there any way I can make them generic so that they accept any array and then converts it into a string?

```
public static string PointArrayToString(Point[] array) => string.Join(" ", array);
public static string PointArrayToString(string[,] array) => string.Join(" ", array);
```

For example...

```
    public static string PointArrayToString(T[] array) => string.Join(" ", array);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are almost there:

```
public static string PointArrayToString<T>(T[] array) => string.Join(" ", array);
```

And for testing:

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string> { "1", "2", "3", "4" };
List<int> list2 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
string[,] collection3 = new string[,] { { "a", "b" }, { "a", "c" } };

var result1 = PointArrayToString(list1.ToArray());
var result2 = PointArrayToString(list2.ToArray());
var result3 = PointArrayToString(collection3.Cast<string>().ToArray());
```

If you don't feel like converting `ToArray` every time then:

```
public static string PointArrayToString<T>(IEnumerable<T> array) => string.Join(" ", array);
```